# PHP MYSQL Solr auto updating

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, synchronization, auto-update

I am new to Solr and i need to know whether i am thinking correct about Solr and MySQL relation or not.

1. We index data from MySQL to Solr for once and then all add,edit,delete, update queries etc are implemented on Solr and MySQL got no change meanwhile. If we need to update MySQL as well, we will have to export (or some thing like that) from Solr to MySQL to keep MySQL up to date.
   **`Am i thinking Right?`**
2. We only need to index those tables of MySQL on Solr which need search, not all MySQL data?
   **`Am i thinking Right again?`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qn 1. Usual case is that your main data store is MySQL, so Solr is the one that lags. One can either use the [data import handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) or write custom indexing programs to get data from MySQL to Solr.

Qn 2. Along with the fields you want to search (which are indexed fields), you can also keep non-indexed stored fields in Solr. This will help you build your data from Solr itself, without doing a secondary DB query.

Comment: secondary database query will use a mysql table, so that table should also be imported to solr. My question was, the tables not used in search should or shouldn't imported to Solr.

Comment: There is no strict rule for this. It depends on what you want to do. Ideally you only keep the fields you want to search in Solr. Then get the document IDs that match your search from Solr and build your domain objects from the DB. But you can also use Solr for this if you want to avoid doing this two-step query, one to Solr and then one to DB. You need to decide that for yourself.

Comment: thanks, it helped, can you also please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712996/the-best-php-support-for-apache-solr?lq=1